# Is it possible to cite references by topic group rather than key(word)?

Tags: bibtex, citing

A marvelous feature for citing references would be the ability to specify a comma-separated list of topics for each entry in a `.bib` file and have a command (suppose, `\tcite{topiclist}`) automatically expand into an equivalent `\cite` command with all reference keys whose topics list has a nonempty intersection with `topiclist`.

In the example below, I use the `keywords` field of each BiBTeX entry to specify the topics list. Hence the command `\tcite{physics}` determines that references `einstein` and `hawking` contain `physics` as a topic and therefore expands to `\cite{einstein,hawking}`. Likewise, `\tcite{time,space}` determines that three of the entries have topic lists that intersect the set {`time`,`space`} and expands to these three entries: `\cite{hawking,paine,hough}`.

**MWE**

`mybib.bib`:

```
@book{einstein,
    author   = {Einstein, Albert},
    title    = {The World as I See it},
    keywords = {physics}
}
@book{hawking,
    author   = {Hawking, Stephen},
    title    = {A Brief History of Time},
    keywords = {physics,time,space}
}
@book{paine,
    author   = {Paine, X. S.},
    title    = {A Masochist's Guide to Deciphering TeX Errors},
    keywords = {tex,time}
}
@book{hough,
    author   = {Houghendorfer, Owain},
    title    = {LaTeX for Stooges: Moe Curly Braces},
    keywords = {tex,space,stooges}
}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
% Desired code:
% Physics~\tcite{physics} deals with time/space~\tcite{time,space}.

% Equivalent code:
Physics~\cite{einstein,hawking} deals with time/space~\cite{hawking,paine,hough}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Is there a package that does this?

If not, would some kind and brilliant soul be willing to post an implementation of it?

I suspect with something like `pgfkeys` this won't be outside the realm of possibility, although I don't know whether reading/parsing `.bib` file contents, computing intersections of string-valued lists, etc. are readily accomplished in LaTeX.

Please note that I don't have my heart set on using the `keywords` field. The means of specifying the topics list can be anything so long as it can be placed somewhere in or near the BibTeX entry for each reference.

Also note that I'm open to using BibLaTeX or other alternative bibliography packages that can read `.bib` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an `expl3` implementation which uses a `prop` list to store the entries that contain each unique (case-sensitive) keyword, and then collects the entries based on a list of keywords to pass to the citation command.

First you need to read the `.bib` file with `\ReadBibFile{<file-name.bib>}` and then you can cite the entries with `\tcite[<command>]{<keywords>}`. The default `<command>` is `\cite`.

---

The implementation is based on the same principle used by the [`usebib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/usebib) package: it makes `@` an active character which will look for the bib entry, and then it uses a keyval package to parse the keys. This implementation uses `l3keys` to do the parsing. The code below only defines `keywords`, but you can extend this to parse other keys by adding the corresponding key handler.

> [image]

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{einstein,
    author   = {Einstein, Albert},
    title    = {The World as I See it},
    keywords = {physics}
}
@book{hawking,
    author   = {Hawking, Stephen},
    title    = {A Brief History of Time},
    keywords = {physics,time,space}
}
@book{paine,
    author   = {Paine, X. S.},
    title    = {A Masochist's Guide to Deciphering TeX Errors},
    keywords = {tex,time}
}
@book{hough,
    author   = {Houghendorfer, Owain},
    title    = {LaTeX for Stooges: Moe Curly Braces},
    keywords = {tex,space,stooges}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { coto }
  {
    , keywords .code:n = { \coto_add_keywords:n {#1} }
    , unknown .code:n = { } % ignore unknown keys
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \ReadBibFile { m } { \coto_read_bib:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \tcite { O{\cite} m }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__coto_tmpa_clist
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \prop_get:NnNTF \g_coto_keywords_prop {##1} \l__coto_tmpa_tl
          { \clist_put_right:Nx \l__coto_tmpa_clist { \l__coto_tmpa_tl } }
          { \msg_error:nnn { coto } { no-entries } {#2} }
      }
    \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l__coto_tmpa_clist
    \use:x { \exp_not:n {#1} { \exp_not:V \l__coto_tmpa_clist } }
  }
% Implementation
\tl_new:N \l_coto_entry_tl
\tl_new:N \l__coto_tmpa_tl
\ior_new:N \l__coto_bib_ior
\clist_new:N \l__coto_tmpa_clist
\quark_new:N \q__coto_stop
\prop_new:N \g_coto_keywords_prop
\cs_new_protected:Npn \coto_add_keywords:n #1
  { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__coto_add_to_keyword:n }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__coto_add_to_keyword:n #1
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \g_coto_keywords_prop {#1} \l__coto_tmpa_tl
      {
        \clist_if_in:NnF \l__coto_tmpa_tl {#1}
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l__coto_tmpa_tl { , \l_coto_entry_tl }
            \prop_gput:NnV \g_coto_keywords_prop {#1} \l__coto_tmpa_tl
          }
      }
      { \prop_gput:NnV \g_coto_keywords_prop {#1} \l_coto_entry_tl }
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:nnTF { V } { T, F, TF }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \coto_read_bib:n #1
  {
    \file_if_exist:nTF {#1}
      {
        \group_begin:
          \__coto_bib_setup:
          \file_input:n {#1}
        \group_end:
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { coto } { file-not-found } {#1} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__coto_bib_setup:
  {
    \char_set_catcode_group_begin:N \{
    \char_set_catcode_group_end:N \}
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \%
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \,
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \@
    \char_set_active_eq:NN \@ \__coto_read_bib_entry:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__coto_read_bib_entry:w #1
  # {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \@
    \__coto_read_bib_entry:n
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__coto_read_bib_entry:n #1
  { \__coto_read_bib_entry_aux:w #1 , \q__coto_stop }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__coto_read_bib_entry_aux:w #1 , #2 \q__coto_stop
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_coto_entry_tl {#1}
    \keys_set:nn { coto } {#2}
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \@
  }
\msg_new:nnn { coto } { file-not-found } { File~`#1'~not~found. }
\msg_new:nnn { coto } { no-entries } { No~entries~found~for~keyword~`#1'. }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ReadBibFile{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
% Desired code:
With \verb|\tcite|: Physics~\tcite{physics} deals with time/space~\tcite{time,space}.

% Equivalent code:
With \verb| \cite|: Physics~\cite{einstein,hawking} deals with time/space~\cite{hawking,paine,hough}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow. A thousand thanks.

Comment: @COTO You're welcome! :-)